# Checking multi websites for search box?

Tags: python, web-scraping

need a method to **scrape** multiple websites to check for the existence of search functionality(a search box) in them .

my trail included the use of "BeautifulSoup" but not all websites use similar class names plus there is google custom search. the method I am using currently is very crude and only partially detects the presence of search box.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,Comment
page = requests.get(url)
SA = 0
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
result=soup.find_all('input')
tags = []
for x in result:
    tags.extend(str(x))
strings = []
i=0
sentence = ''.join(tags)
if 'search' in sentence:
    print('there is a search bar')
else
    print('there is no search bar')
```

I am expecting a better method that can successfully detect whether there is a search box present or not.

Comment: you are not using class. You are using type /tag. Can you provide some failing examples you would like to see found.

Comment: yes currently i am using tags.previously i tried it using classes like

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
soup.find('form',{'class':'search-form'})
soup.find('form',{'class':'content-search'})
soup.find('form',{'class':'Search_bar'})
soup.find('form',{'class':'form-search'})

Comment: failing examples? Urls

Comment: http://www.pondiuni.edu.in/ uses class name "search-form"
https://www.uohyd.ac.in/ uses class name "input-box"

many other sites uses different name for there class

Comment: seems like using input tag is a good approach and then testing if search is within html of matched elements. You can also pass lists of selectors separated with "," to select e.g. select('input, .search,...........)

Comment: yes but it cannot detect if a page is using Google custom search

Comment: what does that look like? url?

Comment: http://www.iitg.ac.in/  uses google custom search and my code cannot detect it